# Expected performance of virtualized PCI DMA?

Tags: qemu

I've gotten a test rig setup that performs DMA writes to a 64bit linux guest. Using DMA transfer sizes of 4096 bytes, I am only able to get a throughput of about 80MB/sec which seems awfully low...

On the linux guest, I have a coherrent buffer setup which is written to by the virtual device, once an IRQ is received, the buffer is summed (to verify data integrity). The process then repeats.

On the device, I am simply using `pci_dma_write`

When running my test, the cpu usage of qemu (on the host), pegs the CPU (or at least one core), which seems strange to me.

Thoughts? I would think a much higher bandwidth is possible, but I am not sure.

Edit:
 I am running with the following command: `/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -device e1000,netdev=n0,id=nic0 -netdev user,id=n0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device dma_demo_device debian8.qcow2`
 Clearly I have the enable-kvm flag, however, I don't know how I can verify that it really is interfacing with KVM (which is definitely installed on the system) 
 As for getting my metric of 80MB/sec, I request a large number of transfers and simply log the time it starts and stops, in the guest. While the timing may be off, I don't see if that could account for much of a difference...

Comment: What kind of qemu back-end did you use? Is it KVM or TCG (which is default one)? Did you measure your results inside guest runtime? How did you request time period values for "80 MB per second" value? In case of TCG it may be timekeeping issue due to assumptions of TCG back-end. (time periods measured from guest point of view are not realistic)

Comment: @Jettatura I've clarified the original post